# How to use the result of a SUBSTRING as column definition in an INSERT INTO query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, substring

I need to dynamically create INSERT INTO statements with column definition, to prevent IDENTITY_INSERT problems. I already found out how to retrieve the column-list of tables and also a way, to put it all together.

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @columnlist nvarchar(4000)

// Result of this query e.g.: "[cid], [pid], [nid], [uid], [subject]"
SET @columnlist = (SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'from_table' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION FOR XML path('')), 3,  200000))

SET @query ='INSERT INTO to_table (' + @columnlist + ')  SELECT  ' + @columnlist + ' FROM from_table;'
exec sp_executesql @query
```

Anyways i don't feel comfortable with this solution, because i am building a string, which gets executed afterwards. I am looking for a solution with a query, that executes directly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic SQL really is your only option and it can be safe and reliable if you use good practices like always using `quotename()`. The only other gotcha is if the query grows over 4000 characters in which case you should use `nvarchar(max)` and use `exec (@query)` instead of `sp_executesql`.